# Distinct rows and join another column from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2012, distinct

I query this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CategoryId
FROM Products
```

and it retrieves the distinct categories in the table *Products*, flawlessly.

But when I try to get the respective *CategoryName* from the table *Categories* in the same query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.CategoryId, c.CategoryName
FROM Products p
INNER JOIN Categories c
ON p.CategoryId = c.CategoryId
```

it retrieves much more rows that ‘it should’.

To be clear, I just need to know in the same result set, what is the name of the distinct categories in the table products. Is that possible?

The schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Categories](
    [CategoryId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CategoryName] [nvarchar](75) NOT NULL,
    [dbts] [timestamp] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products](
    [ProductId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Year] [nvarchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [SupplyId] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [SupplyName] [nvarchar](80) NULL,
    [CategoryId] [int] NULL,
    [cdate] [datetime] NULL,
    [mdate] [datetime] NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_products] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProductId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: what is the output your were expecting ?

Comment: Because the `DISTINCT` is happening *after* the `JOIN`. Put your `DISTINCT` inside a sub-query and `JOIN` to that.

Comment: The query should work, if `CategoryId` is the primary key of `Categories`

Comment: I expect to get the same number of rows of the first query, plus the respective _CategoryName_. I do understand that the second query is wrong, but how do I get the _CategoryName_?

Comment: tell us the output of this query: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT 1 FROM Categories GROUP BY categoryid HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT categoryname) > 1) x;`

Comment: I'm doing this on SQL Server 2012

Comment: please show the table schema and expcted result..only query wont help!

Comment: @ypercube CategorieId is not the primary key. It should be?

Comment: if you are joining condition is using the categoryid , what is wrong with this `select distinct categoryid,categoryname from Categories`?

Comment: @user3447289 : mate....save all of us some time...paste your schema...it'll be lot quicker there after!!! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor I'll do that.

Comment: I feel like the schema is shot in the first place.  Probably, there's a lot of products with the same name (different id), and joining it is what's causing the problem.  Hopefully, your post of schema will show what is happening and we could better help you.

Comment: The only way your second query could return more rows than the first query would be if categories has the same categoryID listed multiple times with different names; as ypercube trying to ascertain I believe.  you comment that categoieID is not the primary key of categories... what is (that's what your join should be on)

Comment: I'm sorry guys. I've messed up.
The second query is right! The problem was in table Categories that had duplicated IDs. Just like @xQbert pointed out.

Comment: This answers the question: joins are made with primary keys! I didn't have a primary key in categories table.

Comment: @csraguiar :  so problem solved?? :)

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Could you please mark as answered? I can't do that. :)

Comment: @csraguiar : i would vote to close it as it as the error could not be replicated anymore....welcome to SO fella!! :D

Comment: @NoobEditor thank you. :) how do I vote to close it? should I delete the question?

Comment: This question stemmed from bad data; or a misunderstanding of data; not bad code.  You should also note that you don't need primary keys to do joins; they help, but a unique index would also work. and you can join to non-unique/keys but you should expect to get the results you did in this exercise!

Comment: bad data indeed. the query was right and should do what I expected if the data was right. other than that, the question is irrelevant. thank you @xQbert.

Comment: @csraguiar : as of now u can not vote to close...u need to get enough reputation for it first....if u wish u can delete the question but that would take back the reputation *(+5)* which u got from upvote...your choice!! ;)